# Magento does not read phtml file

Tags: magento2

I'm absolute newbie at magento2.

My code:

> Block/Index.php

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
    class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {

    }
```

> Controller/Index.php

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

    class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        protected $_pageFactory;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
        {
            $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
            return parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            return $this->_pageFactory->create();
        }
    }
```

> Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route frontName="helloworld" id="helloworld">
        <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

> etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
</module>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/template/index/index.phtml

```
<h2>Helloworld</h2>
```

> Vendor/Module/view/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Index" name="index.index" template="Vendor_Module::index/index.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Unfortunately

### Helloworld

is not displaying.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you send from which url are you trying to access page ? Also Vendor/Module/view/frontend/template/index.php file should be .phtml

Comment: Where is the layout.xml it should be helloworld_index_index.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/index/index.phtml`

and not

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/template/index/index.phtml`

note:

`template` in Magento 1

`templates` in Magento 2

2/

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml`

and not

`Vendor/Module/view/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml`

Answer (score 1):

If you rename tha template file from `index.php` to `index.phtml`, move it to `view/frontent/templates/index/` and add a layout xml file in `view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml` your code should work.

For example if you just want to output the content of your template in the content area, you can use the following xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="index.index"  template="Vendor_Module::index/index.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

For using your bock you need to replace `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` with `Vendor\Module\Block\Index` in the layout xml.

Comment: I've done your suggested changes, but still no result and no errors as well...
I have updated my code above.

Comment: please check if you have enabled layout caching, if yes you have to flush that cache. But it would be better to deactivate it

Comment: There is a type in the template path, I updated my answer too - it must be "templates" not "template"

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 mistakes in the code

1. Vendor/Module/view/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml this should be in  Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml
2. Vendor/Module/view/frontend/template/index/index.phtml file this should be Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/index/index.phtml

Make above to changes and flush cache and then check